# sinon.js on nodejs: require('sinon') returns empty object

Tags: node.js, sinon

I want to use `sinon` on node.js and mocha. I am do following in my test file:

```
var sinon = require('sinon')
```

After that `sinon` var is empty object. `global.sinon` is undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you installed sinon? `npm install sinon`?

Comment: If your using node, `global.sinon` will never be created.

Comment: Of course I have installed `sinon`. I have added an extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `sinon` together with `mocha` you should require `sinon` from `mocha` command line (or inside `mocha.opts` file):

```
mocha --require sinon
```

And after that regular `require` works as expected.